# Finding ArrayList elements in ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have two ArrayList `userActions` and `actionsToCheck` of type `enum Action`.

I want to check if all the elements in `actionsToCheck` is present in `userActions`.

Is the following good enough or is there a better way?

```
private boolean actionsAllowed(ArrayList<Action> userActions, ArrayList<Action> actionsToCheck){
    return actionsToCheck.stream().allMatch(action-> actionAllowed(userActions,action));
}

private boolean actionAllowed(ArrayList<Actions> userActions, Action action){
    return userActions.stream().anyMatch(userAction -> userAction == action);
}

ArrayList<Actions> userAction=new ArrayList<>();
userAction.add(ADD_USER);
userAction.add(DELETE_USER);
userAction.add(MODIFY_USER);

ArrayList<Actions> actionsToCheck=new ArrayList<>();
actionsToCheck.add(ADD_USER);
actionsToCheck.add(DELETE_USER);

actionsAllowed(userAction,actionsToCheck) //should return true
```

Comment: Whether or not it is good, it is unreadable. I suggest making a predicate function out of this, naming it well, and reducing the "chained calls off the edge of the stream".

Comment: added another function and sample test. better?

Answer (score 2):

You could simply use `Collection.containsAll(collection)` to do your check.

In addition I would recommend using `EnumSet` instead of `ArrayList`.